# fonts not working any more (flex)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts

my fonts got screwed up when moving my flash-project to flex. They don't show up any more (strange thing is I don't get any error messages).

Please - can somone help me out with this problem? Thank you.

```
[Embed(source="../../../../../assets/fonts/Orbitron/TTF/orbitron-medium.ttf", fontFamily="Orbitron", fontWeight="medium", mimeType='application/x-font', embedAsCFF='false')]
public static const OrbitronMedium:Class;

private var font:String;
font = new Library.OrbitronMedium();

private var statsTxtFormat:TextFormat;
statsTxtFormat = new TextFormat();
statsTxtFormat.font = font;
statsTxtFormat.bold = false;
statsTxtFormat.size = 14;
statsTxtFormat.color = 0xfdfea1;
statsTxtFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
statsTxtFormat.kerning = true;
statsTxtFormat.letterSpacing = 1;
```

Comment: Try loading your font in a directory which is not nested too deep. You could try out with just one font to ascertain whether this could be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if "../../../../../" could be the problem.

Try moving the font closer to the file, it will reduce the chances of a bad embed.

Comment: Ok i will give this a try. But all my images and sound files are deep nested, too. So I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Problem solved.:) The path was not the cause.
These two links helped a lot to solve my problem:
[link]http://www.spikything.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/06/how-to-embed-fonts-in-pure-as3/
[link]http://blog.creonfx.com/adobe-flex/embed-font-in-flex4-actionscript-project